# Change GridRowStyle in Telerik WinForm

Tags: winforms, coding-style, grid, telerik

i have a field in my database for detect font syle of a row.
font syle is Regular where it is true.
I want to changing my row style when select it. i write this :

```
private void myGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
DataBaseComponent.EditFieldofObject(object1.Serial, true);
if (myGrid.SelectedRows[0].VisualElement != null) 
    myGrid.SelectedRows[0].VisualElement.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(178))); 
myGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells["myField"].Value = true;
}
```

but it doesnot work and i must bind grid again to see this change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ItemDataBound instead of SelectionChanged?  This will work for your needs.

```
    protected void myGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem dataBoundItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            if (dataBoundItem["ColumnName"].Text.ToString() == "True")
            {
                // Do something here
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a good [article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdconditionalformatting.html) on Telerik explaining it.